# Multiple varargout matlab error

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, variadic-functions

I have created a multiwindow GUI and have been confused with such a problem for a while:

I've got main GUI window with two buttons which are leading to two another GUI windows. One does not have an `output_fcn` options and closing normally, but another GUI window has 4 output arguments, which I use in subwindow and the problem is:

> Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

when i'm trying to close the window. 
Here some code:

```
function varargout = changeme_dialog1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = get(handles.varP1,'String');
varargout{2} = get(handles.varP2,'String');
varargout{3} = get(handles.varP3,'String');
varargout{4} = get(handles.varP4,'String');
```

An error first appears in the `varargout{1}`.

What's the problem?

Comment: Take a look at the type of `handles`. Is it a `struct`? That seems to be what the error is complaining about. Try doing `dbstop if error` before running it so you can examine its state in the debugger.

Comment: Do you close the figure before the execution of `changeme_dialog1_OutputFcn`? Specifically, wherever it is you close the figure, do you also run `uiresume` after closing?

Comment: @ThP My closing function:
`function figure_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
uiresume(handles.figure1);`

Comment: @AndrewJanke I put a breakpoint mark at the line `varargout{1}...` and in comand window asked about handles. It turns:
`handles = 
              figure1: 173.0305
             uipanel1: 174.0305
               text23: 272.0305
                varP4: 271.0305
                varP3: 270.0305
                varP2: 269.0305
                varP1: 268.0305`

Does it mean it is a struct?

Comment: Yep, looks like it. You can confirm that by doing `class(handles)` to see exactly what type it is. It's also possible that that function gets called multiple times, with different values for `handles`. Make sure you're looking at the run where the error is raised: take that line-based breakpoint out, and let it run until the `dbstop if error` breakpoint is hit, and check `handles` there as well. Based on this output, I don't see what's going wrong, so the next thing to do is narrow down where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem several years ago, and am quite surprised if this turns out to be the same issue. The thing is, by the time `OutputFcn` is called, the `handles` structure was already deleted\cleared, for this reason you are getting an error because you're trying to reference something that MATLAB doesn't even recognize as a `struct`.

What I did was [storing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) the outputs in `appdata` and [retrieving](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) them during `OutputFcn` (note: nothing's stopping you from retrieving the data in the calling code, but if you respect *scope* this is a more "correct" way to go about it IMO):

- Step 1: Save outputs to appdata upon clicking a "close window" button:

  ```
  function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    setappdata(0,'Output',{...
      [handles.Hor1 handles.Ver1], [handles.Hor2 handles.Ver2]...
      [handles.Hor3 handles.Ver3], [handles.Hor4 handles.Ver4]...
      })

    delete(handles.figure1); %// This actually initiates figure removal
  ```

  (Here `Hor1` ... `Ver4` are just some example fields in handles.. In your case it would be `get(handles.varP1,'String');` etc.)
- Step 2: Retreive outputs from appdata, [clearing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmappdata.html) it afterwards

  ```
  function varargout = changeme_dialog1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    ...
    varargout{1}=getappdata(0,'Output'); %// <== Wizardry Part 2
    rmappdata(0,'Output') ;
    ...
  ```

I hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.